# How to insert long number in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have number of type 123.69727407930787989 and I need to store it in mysql database using java.

1. Data type that should be used in java.
2. Data type that should be used in mysql.
3. Do i need to round of this number if i want to storeit in xxx.xxxxx format.  How to round off number in this format in java

Comment: double in java and varchar in mysql should work

Comment: but then how can i run aggregate functions in mysql on this value if i store it in varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE 1: You should use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in java

RE 2: You should use  DECIMAL(M,D) data type in mysql e.g.for 123.69727407930787989 DECIMAL(20,17) where M 1 to 65 digits and D is 0 to 30 digits

RE 3:
     (a) Do i need to round of this number if i want to storeit in xxx.xxxxx format?
     (Ans.) Its depends your requirements what you want

(b) How to round off number in this format in java?

```
java.math.BigDecimal bigDecimal = new java.math.BigDecimal("123.69727407930787989",new java.math.MathContext(5));
```

Comment: If i take DECIMAL(3,17) then my number should always in this format like i can store 23.898 in it or not? or i need to change it in the format specified.

Comment: In the case of DECIMAL(20,17), you can insert 0.0 to 999.9999999999999999. So, just take value of M and D what would be max value for M and D respectively and M>=D

Answer (score 0):

You can create decimal column (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) in MySQL table.

To read/write the column in java use BigDecimal class. It has the method for rounding

```
public BigDecimal round(MathContext mc)
```

Comment: If you can provide me example that will be much better.Actually sometimes i get value 26.135235252524 and sometimes 21.38740327440325703255783557 & sometimes 29.32434 and when i try to store it in mysql then i am getting com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of 
range value for column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480804/mysql-cant-handle-large-values-even-with-decimal an example of max digits in decimal and rounding. Try yourself to write the code and post here specific problem