# How do I convert a C# BigInteger into a MySQL DECIMAL(36,18)?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to store a BigInteger as a DECIMAL(36,18) in C#.
When I try to add the value like this:

```
public void AddTrade(BigInteger price) {
    _connection.Open();
    var command = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Prices (Price) VALUES (@Price);", _connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _connection.Close();
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Parameter type BigInteger is not supported;
```

Here is how I created the table:

```
public void CreatePriceTable() {
    _connection.Open();
    var createTable = new MySqlCommand(
        @"
        CREATE TABLE `Prices` (
        Price DECIMAL(36,18) NOT NULL,
        ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;"
        , _connection);
    createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _connection.Close();
```

}

I wasn't able to find the solution in any documentation and hope someone can help me with this. Thank you!

edit:
The reason I need to use a BigInteger is because I am receiving a price in Wei (the smallest unit on the Ethereum blockchain) as BigInteger. One Ether is 1000000000000000000 Wei. Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276115/how-to-store-cryptocurrency-balance-in-mysql) suggested using DECIMAL(36,18) for Wei.

Comment: you can directly convert price to double

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to convert a BigInteger to a decimal (Base 10) string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154304/fastest-way-to-convert-a-biginteger-to-a-decimal-base-10-string)

Comment: Most likely it expects C# 'decimal' type for column of type 'DECIMAL'. Not `BigInteger`. BigInteger has unlimited precision and in general case cannot be stored in 'DECIMAL' column anyway.

Comment: BigInteger  doesn't exist in c# as datatype getting down it it an int32. But i don't understand why you want an Integer converted into a decimal

Comment: I edited the post to answer some of the questions.

Comment: `DECIMAL(36,0)` might make more sense

Comment: @Charlieface I agree, thank you.

Comment: `BigInteger doesn't exist in c# as datatype` - it's not a CLR type, but it's certainly been available in C#, since framework 4.0 days.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler than expected. Calling ToString() does the job:

```
public void AddTrade(BigInteger price) {
    _connection.Open();
    var command = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Prices (Price) VALUES (@Price);", _connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price.ToString();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Except you have decimal column, which means your intention was to store fractional values (ETH) and you write integer (Wei) there.

Comment: You could just cast to a decimal `Value = (decimal)price`

Comment: @Evk good point. I'll change it to DECIMAL(36,0)